# How do I scroll long text - left or right - in a IONIC input field on my IOS device?

Tags: css, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic5

I have created an **ionic** input field form, but when generating this app, I face some problems like - writing long text in the input field, text not swipe(scroll) left or right. I search for a solution long time but have not found it.

NB: android device working fine, faces this problem in **IOS** device

**Here is my code sample and image**

```
<IonItem>
   <IonLabel>Description</IonLabel>
   <IonInput></IonInput>
</IonItem>
```

[image: scroll not work for long text in ionic- IOS]

Comment: try long Press your space key and then swipe.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib try it. but not working in IONIC IOS app.